# Java and Serial Port

Tags: avr, java

I am able to control the speed and direction of 2 DC motors using an AVR-based microcontroller board (see [here](http://robokits.co.in/shop/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=6&products_id=312&zenid=959a607fe6e05d81564225801f044e1a) for details) currently through hyperterminal (Flash Magic).

Is it possible to do the same through a Java-based GUI program instead?

I mean the speed entered in the textfield of the GUI being sent to the COMPort instead of the one entered in hyperterminal. If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

There are com-port libraries available for java.

[RXTX](http://users.frii.com/jarvi/rxtx/) seems to be one of the most prominent.
[Here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Serial_Java) is a long discussion about how to use RXTX and an alternative, called JavaComm.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264277/java-serial-communication-on-windows) is a question on StackExchange asking essentially exactly what you are asking.

---

Note: I'm assuming you want to *write* a java application to do what you describe (otherwise, why would the application being java-based be relevant?)

If not, please update your question.

---

#### Edit:

If you're in control of the USB-serial converter, you could use the [jD2XX library](http://bleyer.org/jd2xx/), which wraps the FTDI [D2XX](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm) driver API.

This is an *excellent* API, but it will **only** work with FTDI usb-serial converters.

Comment: I have used RXTX extensively and it was painful to get everything working just how I wanted. I hope @ABES knows what delays do in a control system. I will admit, getting the first bit started was easy, just getting it fine tuned took time.